# Selecting English for system messages on Windows10

Tags: postgresql, localization, psql, postgresql-10

I am using Postgres 10.5 on my local computer. In `psql`, all system messages are in the default system language. I want to get them in English. I tried changing `postgresql.conf` as below;

```
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Unfortunately the language didn't change.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lc_messages = 'C'` for English log messages.

This selects the built-in English messages with no translation and works on all operating systems.